# Correct usage of expression "or did I"

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

In the opening sentence of an article I am writing, I state something that would seem obvious to the reader, but that I will challenge (since I will be closing with a slightly different conclusion). The sentence is:

So I achieved the most amazing xyz feat... or did I?

Is the usage/grammar correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think, like in this example: ''This dog is very big, isn't it?''.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, your example is how I commonly see the expression used, but the final question comes as a "negative", that is, "isn't it?"  I was wondering if it is still correct to use the positive form. In your example, would it be correct to say "The dog is very big, or is it?" ?

Comment: It works in the positive form too.

Comment: An ellipsis is not necessary to separate a [tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question), which your *or* construction with *do* is. The *or* provides the same balance as the normal *not*. A coma will do, but a dash or the ellipsis might imply a longer pause for deeper reflection.

Comment: @ScotM A coma signifies a longer pause than an ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not aware of any style books that will verify what you've done, personal experience tells me your construction of an ellipsis followed by "or did [pronoun]?" is standard practice.

As an alternative, you could also use an em dash and make it, "I achieved the most amazing feat—or did I?"